# New rocky mountain soul 29 making creaks by the bb

Tags: bottom-bracket, creak

Not to sure what it's coming from I don't have the tools to take the crank off or adjust the bb. The funny thing I don't get is that the creak is gone the next time I ride my bike then when I may go over a root or something and hour and a half into my ride the creak comes back then get progressivly worse the more I pedal. Then the harder I pedal the sounds gone. The lighter I pedal the sounds there. Th e only side it comes from is the left. I dont get it at all. I'm. It really bike inclined which is odd since I work as a vehicle mechanic. Any one have any suggestions.oh and the bb is a shinamo un-26 sealed square tapered bearing. And the bike is 2 months old

Comment: Did your lbs give you a free 30 day check-up when you bought the bike? If they did bring it in for a check. You want them to resolve this before you or the bike suffer permanant damage.

Comment: There are lots and lots of previous posts regarding squeaks, creaks, ticks, and clicks coming from the bottom bracket. (http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bottom-bracket) Unfortunately there is no easy answer, but you'll find lots and lots of info in those relevant posts.

Comment: Take a look through the tags @WTHarper posted, there are a number of answers that might help. If you look through those and nothing helps, post a video with good quality sound, and if you really think it is the BB, remove the chain and give it a few cranks forward and backward to demonstrate the issue.

Comment: I count seven prior threads on creaking BBs.  Better to review those than to wait for answers here.

Answer (score 1):

The crank arm is most likely loose on the square shaft BB. Remove it, clean it, grease it and retorque it in place.

Comment: You aren't supposed to grease the square taper interface.

Answer (score 0):

There are many possible causes. But it's likely the cranks are slightly loose on their axle. Vigorous pedalling and warming up during the ride make the situation worse.

I have posted a detailed answer [here](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/124/creaking-from-cranks-spindle-how-to-fix). Please scroll down to see the answers from me and Deemar.